# Convert table data to Classifier data

Tags: data, machine-learning

I want to convert excel data into Classifier acceptable data. For Eg, the inbuilt Titanic data for Classifier is structured as below:

> {"1st", 29., "female"} -> "survived"

I have 4 columns in Excel "Product","Design","Color","Sold/NorSold" . I can't figure out how I can convert this data to Classifier acceptable data. Any help would be appreciated. I tried using 'Rule' but the results weren't what I wanted.

Comment: Have a look at Menu/Help/Wolfram Documentation/Import and get your data imported into Mma. It is straightforward. Then you can apply `Classify `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SemanticImport to import your data. This code is based on my data in csv file:

```
innovate1 = SemanticImport["C:\\Users\\MCS\\Documents\\innovate.csv"]
```

then you can associate the data using

```
inno1 = Normal@innovate1[All, Sequence[Most@# -> Last@#] &]
```

You will get output of form:

```
    {{0, "male", "AboveAvg", 46, "PrivateBank"} -> 
  "Innovate", {0, "male", "BelowAvg", 45, "PrivateBank"} -> 
  "NotInnovate", {1, "male", "BelowAvg", 45, "PrivateBank"} -> 
  "Innovate"......
```

Comment: Thank you that works! I was using Import instead of SemanticImport